# Can an ocean moon with a mass of 0.5 earth masses stabilize the axial tilt of a planet two times bigger than earth?

Tags: science-based, planets, moons, astronomy

The world will going to be the homeworld of an hairless feline humanoid race, but I want to see the plausibility of this scenario?

Comment: To whoever marked this as `too broad`: you need to explain why. IMHO, this is a very specific orbital mechanics question.

Answer (score 5):

## Almost certainly.

First of all, I will assume that "two times bigger than Earth" means twice the Earth's mass. I will also assume that all other characteristics of the planet and the solar system (such as the mass of the central star and the planet's radius) are identical to those of Earth.
The paper [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0019103511001989) mentions the following equation for determining whether a given planet, orbited by a given moon, has a stable axial tilt:
$$\frac{m_s}{m_p} >> \frac{9m_*}{4\pi\rho_pa_p^3}$$
Here, $m_s$ is the mass of the moon, $m_p$ is the mass of the planet, $m_*$
 is the mass of the star which the planet/moon system orbits, $\rho_p$ is the density of the planet (assuming the satellite's density is the same, which is a questionable assumption but likely should not cause extensive consequences for the calculations), and $a_p$ is the radius of the planet's orbit around the star. Taking the star's mass to be equal to the Sun's mass and the planet's density and orbit to be the same as Earth's, the equation reduces to $$\frac{1}{4} >> 0.0000000766.$$ This is definitely a true statement, and will almost certainly remain true when all simplifying assumptions are removed. Therefore the planet's axial tilt will remain stable, even taking into account the differing densities of the planet and moon and even if the planet is instead twice the Earth's radius.

Comment: Plus one for an excellent answer. Glad you showed how you simplified your calculation, and the reasons why the simplifications didn't matter for the result. Hope to see more answers and questions from you.